# Creating an auction list (java)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a code for an auction so that when the auction starts, a dog is given a number. The first auction created will get number 1, next number 2, and so on.

Problem is, the code for the auction does not list the dogs by the auction. Rather it is listed by registration.

For example:
Registered dogs

- Bowie
- Anna
- Maya

**(Auction process)**

Command: Start auction

Dog name: Maya

Output: Maya has been put in **auction #2**

---

Command: Start auction

Dog name: Bowie

Output: Bowie has been put in **auction #0**

---

This is my code:

```
private void startAuction() {

    boolean current = false;

    do {
        System.out.println("Dog name: ");
        String dogName = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();

        if (dogName.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Error: Name can't be empty.");
            continue;           
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dogs.size(); i++) {
            if (dogName.equals(dogs.get(i).getName())) {
                auction.add(new Auction(dogName));

                System.out.printf(dogName + " has been put up for auction in auction #%d", i);
                System.out.println();
                current = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        if (current == false) {
            System.out.println("Error: no such dog in the register");
        }
    } while(true);
```

I'm a beginner and slightly confused. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that after getting the name of the dog to auction, you search for that dog in the list, printing the index of where the dog is in the list. What you need to do to fix this is have another counter variable that counts the number of auctioned dogs, incrementing each time. The code would look something like this:

```
    private void startAuction() {

    boolean current = false;
    int auctionCount = 1;//Declare the current auction we are on

    do {
        System.out.println("Dog name: ");
        String dogName = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();

        if (dogName.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Error: Name can't be empty.");
            continue;           
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dogs.size(); i++) {
            if (dogName.equals(dogs.get(i).getName())) {
                auction.add(new Auction(dogName));

                //Use the auction count here so that it starts at 1 and increases 
                System.out.printf(dogName + " has been put up for auction in auction #%d", auctionCount);from there
                System.out.println();
                auctionCount++;//Make sure the next auction has a number that is one larger
                current = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        if (current == false) {
            System.out.println("Error: no such dog in the register");
        }
    } while(true);
}
```

Comment: why not use the size of the auction list? (assuming it is a list, and no auction is removed)

Comment: but now the auctionCount is stuck at 1.  It's as if the whole list resets once I add another dog to the auction :/